# IE8 hangs when loading multiple charts using google visualization API

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I have been working on a small project of my own.
It requires me to first upload data , process it, and then generate 20 seperate google line charts from generated files.

All the above has been pretty much done, except on IE , the loading of 20 charts seems to hang IE completely.

What I am doing right now is chaining calls from .get(/datasource,... ) to next .get.

So basically what is happening is, each data is being loaded and then google charts are generated for that.then next and then so on.

Everything works pretty well in non IE browsers, Chrome, Firefox, Safari.

Link :http://titans.dasfree.com/chartUpload/prototype.html

Any hints on how to get this done??

### Thanks

Neeraj